# QHash removal of specified position till the end of QHash and update the QList accordingly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a function that, once applied splits a QHash till the end from a given position and needs to update the accompanying QList accordingly to reflect the change of the QHash. The QHash stores as `QHash<QString(Train ID), int(position of train)>` for quick lookup. The QList stores as QList as a list of pointers to objects. The given header for this function is: `QList<FreightCar*> splitTrain(int pos)` and cannot be changed( i.e. can only use as is in header).
I've gotten the function to delete only given value "pos" and doesn't iterate thru the QHash with a For loop with the iterator. After the QHash the QList is updated to the values in the QHash, but not exactly.

Here is the implementation of the function.

```
QList<FreightCar*> FreightTrain::splitTrain(int pos)
{
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    QHash<QString, int>::iterator i;
    QList<FreightCar*>::iterator j;

int posI;
posI = pos;
//removal of posbyid by given id onwards
        for(i = this->posByID.begin(); i != this->posByID.end(); )
        {
                  if(i.value() == posI)
                  {
                      i = this->posByID.erase(i++);
                      posI++;
                  }
                  else
                     i++;

         }
        //end of removal of posbyid by given id onwards

        //Display current values in QHash of posByID
        for(auto i = this->posByID.begin(); i != this->posByID.end(); i++)
        {
            cout << "keyid: " << i.key() << " valpos: " << i.value() << endl;
        };
        //End of display of posByID values




//removal of same ID values from QHASH posbyId in QLIST physicalorder
bool yes;
        for (auto j = this->physicalOrder.begin(); j != this->physicalOrder.end();)
        {
            yes = false;

                   for(auto i = this->posByID.begin(); i != this->posByID.end(); ++i)
                   {
                        if((*j)->getID() == i.key())
                        {
                            if(i.key() == pos)
                            {
                                yes = true;
                                break;
                            }else
                            {
                                yes = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }else if((*j)->getID() != i.key())
                        {
                            yes = true;
                        }
                   }
                if(yes == true)
                {
                  j= this->physicalOrder.erase(j);
                }else
                {j++;};
            }//end of removal of same ID values from posbyId in physicalorder

//display of QList after deletion.
        for (auto j = this->physicalOrder.begin(); j != this->physicalOrder.end(); j++)
        {
            cout << (*j)->toString() << endl;
        }
//end of display of list after deletion.

    return *this;

};
```

Output of program after I've created a few objects(train cars):

[image: output]

The split function needs to remove all values/objects from given position till the end. Thus all values from beginning till provided position needs to be kept.

Each object(Freight Car) in the freight train is created in physical order. Each freight car is given an ID an assigned weight(tonnage) and assigned Type(BOXCAR, GONDOLACAR, TANKCAR, FLATBEDCAR). "valpos" refers to the order in which each car was created 1,2,3,4,5 ect. "keyid" refers to the ID of the freight car in the physical order QList.

Comment: Several things are unclear about your question. What is a train ID? Does that actually identify wagons, not trains? Similar, does "position of train" actually mean "position of car within train"? The main issues of the code seem to be a) assuming that QHash has an iteration order, or that iteration over QHash is something you want to do, ever, and b) being unclear on what code is responsible for clearing what; you have two loops that both modify the QHash, but no clear reason why that should be necessary.

Comment: The program is about Freight Trains, each FreightCar has a type,id,position and tonnage  When a freightcar is added it is placed in order of which it was created in the QList(physicalOrder) as the name states. The QHash is for quick lookup of the cars in the list to state what ID the car has in which order it is in the train.

Comment: @SebastianRedl the ID is just to state what Freight Car you are referring to and each car is placed via physical order (just like trains in real life) one after another. Since you can have 5 FLATBEDCAR's so you will need either physical order or ID to differentiate between the cars.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I can make the ID's whichever number during the creation of the object(freightcar) and can also state which ever tonnage it is and also what car type it belongs to. The cars are placed in order during the creation of each objects one after another this is where the "valpos " is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by copying / pasting the initial loop that runs thru the QHash to run thru the loop again to delete following values, as QHash is the same as QMap the values aren't saved same as an array thus you loop past certain values.